# Mysql configuration problem

Tags: mysql, mysql-error-1045

I have being trying since last night. At first it was working but this morning again its not working. I am installing mysql version 5.0 on vista machine. when i try to configure its says that:
The security settings could not be applied to the database because the connnection had failed with the following error:
Error Nr. 1045
access denied for user 'root'@'localhost'(using password:yes)

if a personal firewall is runnig on your machine plaes make sure you have opened the tcp port 3306 for connections. otherwise no client applicaion can connect to the server. after you have opened the port please press retry to apply the secirity settings.

if you are re-installing after you just installed the mysql server please not that the data directory was not removed automatically. therefore the old password from your last installation is still needed to connect to the server. in this case please select skip now and re-run the configuration wizard from the start menu.

i tried disabling the wirefall, user accounts but getting the same error. can anyone suggest me something please.

Comment: Yes it is. I am a web developer and having Mysql running right is very very much programming related.

Comment: Did you ever get this figured out? What other steps have you taken?

Answer (score 1):

I bet that your password was changed. This error clearly states that you are connecting to a mysql server and that your ports are open and working fine. You may be connecting to the wrong mysql server though. Try re-running the install script to reset the password. If you have no data you would like to keep I would say the easiest way would be to uninstall (and delete the entire mysql directory) and reinstall.

Answer (score 0):

I've had this issue before. I reinstalled MySQL, then ran **MySQL Server Instance Config Wizard**, removed the current instance, and then ran **MySQL Server Instance Config Wizard** again to create a new instance and everything worked fine.